# Python: how to use variables as a string?

Tags: python, django

Supose I have such variables: var1, var2, var3, var4, var 5, ..., var100 (lists and dictionaries are not suitable in my case, because all these vars are class objects).

I must process all them in similar way, for example:

```
if var1:
    print 'var1 is not None'
if var2:
    print 'var2 is not None'
if var3:
    print 'var3 is not None'
...
if var100:
    print 'var100 is not None'
```

In such way I will write 200 hundreds lines of code...

But maybe there is some way to process all of them in `for` statement, like:

```
for i in range(1,101):
    if var%s % i: #I know this is not right, but idea is understood
        print 'var%s is not None' % i
```

So I will write only 3 lines of code.

Is it possible do in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe "lists and dictionaries are not suitable in [your] case".  Why do you think so?

Comment: "lists and dictionaries are not suitable in my case" - unless it's an obscure requirement for an assignment (in that case, smack whoever came up with it), there's absolutely no reason to do so.

Comment: My var1,var2,... are class objects.

Comment: This sounds really odd ... is this homework?

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: How is this relevant?

Comment: No, it is Django project

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: How does this mean lists and dicts aren't suitable? Class objects are first-class objects, they can be stored in data structures and generated dynamically. I don't know much about Django but unless they try to gather classes though static analysis (which would be incredibly stupid and unnecessary for all I know), all of this should also hold for Django classes.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Not in Django models object

Comment: @VitaliPonomar, if this is a Django-specific question, you should tag it as such and explain the Django context.

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: A Python list can store any kind of Python objects.

Comment: in Django: class Model(): var1=models.Charfield()... If it will be a list item or dictionary item I do not know how to call that class property...

Comment: First off, you *can* define such a class completely dynamically, even without using the `class` keyword. For instance, `classes = []; for i in range(10) { class Foo { some_val = i }; classes.append(Foo) }` (sans braces of course) creates ten distinct classes. Second, even if defining them seperately is more readable, you can still put them in a collection afterwards to simplify such tasks in addition to having a dedicated name.

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: This question is a typical instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You aren't asking about your real problem, but rather about how to achieve a particular solution you tried, without explaining the real problem.  Consider to add the real problem to the actual question.

Answer (score 8):

`locals()` returns a dictionary of local variables. Similarly, `globals()` returns a dictionary of global variables. You can find the variable and its value in one of those, depending on where it was defined.

```
for i in range(1,101):
    if ('var%s' % i) in locals():
        print 'var%s is not None' % i
        print locals()['var%s' % i]
```

Comment: It was defind as class properties

Answer (score 5):

I wish you hadn't buried your actual requirement in the *tenth comment* underneath the main question. Actually, it appears that what you want is to dynamically get a property of a class - in this instance, a field in a Django model. That's simple: you just do:

```
getattr(instance, varname)
```

Comment: getattr(user_obj, 'var1') - so simple?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify class attributes dynamically:

```
class A(object):
    pass
for i in range(100):
    setattr(A, "var%i" % i, i)
```

creates a class with 100 attributes called `A.var0` to `A.var99`.  There are two problems with this approach:

1. The attributes are quite inconvenient to access. (This is possible with `getattr()`, but having them in a list would make iterating over them so much easier.)
2. If class `A` has a custom metaclass, it is unclear how that metaclass deals with the dynamically created attributes.

From a quick glance at the Django source code, I can see that `django.db.models.Model` indeed has a custom metaclass, and indeed all attributes must already be defined at class creation time, so the above approach won't work.  You'll have to create the complete class dictionary before actually creating the class.  Here is one approach to do so:

```
model_dict = {}
for i in range(100):
    model_dict["var%i" % i] = models.CharField(max_length=10)
model_dict["var_list"] = model_dict.values()
MyModel = type("MyModel", (models.Model,), model_dict)
```

This uses the [three-parameter form of `type()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) to dynamically create a type.  This part addresses problem 2.

To address problem 1, the above code exposes also adds an attribute to the class that allows to acces all the `models.CharField` instances as a list rather than by name.

Comment: Can you post a link to official docs where decribes this method?

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: I gave you the link to the documentation of `type()`.  What else do you need more information on?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6581949/279627).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [eval](http://mfeuerstein.com/using-variables-as-string-in-python) command.

Hope this helps,

Regards, Maecky

Comment: `eval` is seldom a good solution. Oh, and a heads-up, it tends to attract downvotes here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, this works fine for print method. But if I want to redefine it dynamically, how to use eval() in this case: for i in range(1,101): eval('var%s' % i) = str(i)+a

Comment: `eval()` is a very bad solution in this case.

Comment: @VitaliPonomar: If there are many fields in your model, and you want to do several operations on all of them, you should definitely put them in a list. Really, believe me. If the Django `Model` metaclass insists on them also being available as class attributes, well, they will also have to be class attributes, but this doesn't prevent you from putting them in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Couple different ways to do it, either get the variable from the globals or locals dictionary like so:
`globals()['var1']`

or `import __main__` and use `getattr(__main__,'var1')`

throw those into a for loop, assigning the variable name to a string andhave it returned eg

if your testing that the class exists, use a `try except`

```
import __main__

for i in range(1,101):
  try:
    func = getattr(__main__,'var%s' % i)
    if func is not None:
      print 'var%s is not None' % i
  except:
    print 'var%s does not exist'
```

if it's buried in a class use the class name rather than `__main__`. If the class name is var%s use `getattr` on `func` in the loop above to grab whatever it is you need out of each class.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a list or dictionary actually would be the most appropriate way to solve your problem. In Python, data structures can hold others objects. This includes objects that you create yourself because there is no technical distinction from the programmer's point of view between the types (classes) you define and the ones that are native to Python (string, int, etc.)